# xml file updation in android

Tags: xml, android

I want to do an application in which I want to store setting of my application in `xml` so in need to update `xml` file (updating values of nodes , removing nodes,appending nodes).

In java we  will update xml file using `javax.xml`.transform package classes but it is not available in android so is there any way to update `xml`

(If you know the reason of why android does't have transform package please suggest me).

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the settings for your application you could in to the the [`Preferences` facilities offered by Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

The big benefit of doing it this way is that Preference screens and widgets integrate directly with the storage which makes creating a settings Activity extremely easy.

Comment: What you told is correct but my requirement(to create docx files application and docx is a collection of xml files) is to update xml using either sax,xmlpull   parsers or with any other alternative which are available in android

Answer (score 0):

Android isn't an implementation of the JDK, so there's no guarantee that all the JDK classes will be available in Android.  [Apache Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) provides an implementation of javax.xml.transform, so you might be able to simply include xalan.jar (and its dependencies) in your Android project.  Until you try it out, it's hard to say one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks for reply
What you told is correct in java but when I am using Apache Xalan in to project and when I am running application android is not creating apk files